# Using PostSharp NotifyPropertyChanged, how can you hook into the OnPropertyChanged event

Tags: inotifypropertychanged, postsharp

I am trying to get at the OnPropertyChanged event so that I can mark my class as modified.

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]    
Public Class Employee
{
    private bool hasChange;    
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    private static void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        hasChange = true;
    }
}
```

The `OnPropertyChanged` is most likely wrong but hopefully you get the idea of what I am trying to do?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide your own `OnPropertyChanged` method with the same signature as the one generated by PostSharp. As a result, PostSharp will not generate the method and will use your implementation instead. This also means that you need to raise the event in the method yourself.

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]    
public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool hasChange;    
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        hasChange = true;

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm using postsharp, then in order to override *OnPropertyChanged* method of Postsharp, is this way okay?

Comment: Yes, PostSharp will recognize and use your *OnPropertyChanged* implementation in this case.

Comment: In my case, I have got more than 30 models, to which i need to implement *OnPropertyChange*, (**But** I want to put my own implementation for OnPropertyCahnged of postsharp). Can you suggest the scenario, how to take advantage of PostSharp in this case? I mean, How to override PostSharp's OnPropertyChanged? so that I don't need to implement it all 30 models. (i'm working with notifications stuff for the first time)

Comment: Plus, I could very easily override the behavior of *[Log]* attribute. But i'm little stuck in case of propertychanged stuff. I need little help.